# How can we get this infinite prism lattice to look more like `PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 3}]`?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, polyhedra

This is D$_3$h prism with order 12 (8 currently, needs 4 more edges) and rotational symmetry D$_3$ with order 6.

[A d=11 version is shown here.](http://forums.anandtech.com/showpost.php?p=36838113&postcount=1)

Using this code:

```
d = 5;
x = {};
For[t = 1, t <= d, t++,
 If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, 1, 1} <-> {t + 1, 1, 1}]];
 For[r = 2, r <= d, r++,
  If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, r, 1} <-> {t + 1, r, 1}]];
  For[i = 2, i <= r, i++,
   If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, r, i} <-> {t + 1, r, i}]];
   (* Rows *)
   AppendTo[x, {t, r, i - 1} <-> {t, r, i}];
   (* Right Diagonals *)
   AppendTo[x, {t, r - 1, i - 1} <-> {t, r, i}];
   ];
  For[i = r, i > 1, i--,
   (* Left Diagonals *)
   AppendTo[x, {t, r, i - 1} <-> {t, r - 1, i - 1}];
   ];
  ]
 ]
a = Graph3D[x]
```

we get a prism lattice. I would like a way to color either the vertices or edges of a few of the sides to get something like `PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 3}]`. We cannot do anything that allows `tri[t,r,i]` to execute because there will be some duplicates. (It must remain a place-holder). Any suggestions?

**EDIT Replacing `tri[t,r,i]` with `{t,r,i}` cleans up the algorithm.**

Comment: Could you begin by constructing the prism using http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html or `BoundaryMeshRegion`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed `tri` to `List` of your code.

```
d = 9; x = {};
For[t = 1, t <= d, t++, If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, 1, 1} <-> {t + 1, 1, 1}]];
  For[r = 2, r <= d, r++,  If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, r, 1} <-> {t + 1, r, 1}]];
   For[i = 2, i <= r, i++,  If[t < d, AppendTo[x, {t, r, i} <-> {t + 1, r, i}]];
    AppendTo[x, {t, r, i - 1} <-> {t, r, i}];
    AppendTo[x, {t, r - 1, i - 1} <-> {t, r, i}]];
   For[i = r, i > 1, i--,
    AppendTo[x, {t, r, i - 1} <-> {t, r - 1, i - 1}]]]
  ];
```

**Update2**

You can use also `VertexCoordinates` with `ShearingTransform` and  `ScalingTransform`.

```
y = Cases[VertexList@Graph3D@x, 
    {d, _, _} | {_, d, _} | {1, _, _} | {_, _, 1} | {_, a_, a_}];

vertCoo = Composition[
        ShearingTransform[\[Pi]/6, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}],
        ScalingTransform[Sqrt[3]/2, {0, 0, 1}]] /@ (VertexList@Graph3D@x);

Graph3D[x, GraphHighlight -> y, VertexCoordinates -> vertCoo]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Update**

extracted vertex from undirected graph,

```
vertex = VertexList@Graph3D@x;
```

and selected faces vertex.

```
y = Cases[vertex, {d, _, _} | {_, d, _} | {1, _, _} | {_, _, 1} | {_, a_, a_}];
Graph3D[x, GraphHighlight -> y]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And I tried the reversed case.

```
Graph3D[x, GraphHighlight -> Complement[vertex, y]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Original**

deleted

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred Kline Thank you for introducing nice diagram.